# How to subscribe viewController reference to willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm pretty new to objective c so i'm probably over looking basic stuff here. I have reference to a view controller and I would like this view controller to subscribe/observe a handler for `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` My code looks like the following below.

```
UIViewController* globalVC

@implementation my_API

+ (void)render:(){
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:globalVC selector:@selector(willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:) name:@"willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation" object:nil];

}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInt
                                        duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

  //do some stuff

}
```

currently with this setup the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method never gets fired.

Edit:

let me add that: my `globalVC` is coming from a third party library (think banner ad or something). That is already a subclass of `UIViewController` and is already initialized when my code is executed. So hence I can't implement my own `willAnimateRotaionToInterfaceOrientation` method without doing something like a class eval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, You don't actually need to register for any notifications.  Per Apple's documentation on [Supporting Multiple Interface Orientations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html):

> When the orientation of an iOS–based device changes, the system sends
>   out a UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification notification to let any
>   interested parties know that the change occurred. By default, the
>   UIKit framework listens for this notification and uses it to update
>   your interface orientation automatically. This means that, with only a
>   few exceptions, you should not need to handle this notification at
>   all.

The link above has a very clear explanation of how to properly handle device rotation, I suggest you check it out.

In general, you should create your own UIViewController subclass for whatever view controllers you need.  Within your ViewController subclass, just implement the following method and it should be called on device rotation.

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInt
                                    duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

If subclassing the view controller is not an option for some reason, then you can try to handle device rotation from somewhere else using "UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification".  Before doing that, however, you also need to tell your device that you want to receive these notifications.  Example:

```
@implementation MyRotationController

-(void) setupMyRotationController {

    [UIDevice beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                             object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation))
    {
        //do something
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) &&
             isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        //do something else
    }
}


@end
```

Note, I'm lazy and haven't bothered including the code to remove the notification observer when you don't need it any longer, or to stop getting notifications about device rotations.

Comment: So my `globalVC` is coming from a third party library (think banner ad or something). That is already a subclass of UIViewController that is already initialized when my code is executed. So hence I can't implement my own `willAnimateRotaionToInterfaceOrientation`method without doing something like a class eval

Comment: You could method-swizzle your implementation into the view controller provided to you.